# Написать правильный роутер для рендеринг из node js на react?

Tags: reactjs

Как сделать правильный рендеринг, так чтобы ид страниц приходили в props. Потому что как я понял node js наджо по другому составить для react
Мой код роутера

```js
const Router = require('koa-router'),
    router = new Router(),
    React = require('react'),
    ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

router.get('/', async(ctx) => {
    let reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString('компонент react');
    await ctx.render('index', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
})
```

Но такой подход для меня сложный ssh. А простой рендеринг как сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
router.get('/', async ctx => {
   await ctx.render('index');
});
```

И использовать helmet для title

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

class Application extends React.Component{
    constructor(prop){
        super(prop);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='application'>
                <Helmet>
                    <meta charSet='utf-8' />
                    <title>{this.props.title}</title>
                </Helmet>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Application;
```

Более подробно читать Helmet